Isekai manga where the protagonist is reincarnated in another world with his sister and trains to bring her down
I'm looking for a manga where the protagonist jumps in front of a truck to get away from his crazy sister but they both end up being reincarnated in another world where he trains to bring her down.

One of these, possibly; https://www.anime-planet.com/users/RoyalOss/lists/anime-characters-killed-by-truckkun-83507

Is this Did You Think You Could Run After Reincarnating, Nii-san?...?

Five years since I graduated from high school and within those years, I was confined by my younger sister, but it all ended when I ran away and died being hit by a truck. At last I’m free from my devil-like sister! Well, that’s what I thought but my sister was reincarnated with me at the same time in the same world. This time, I’ll escape from my sister’s clutches and live my life in a different world freely. With the strongest weapon and class I received from god.

The main character's parents died at about the same time that he graduated high school. After that, he lived alone with his psychotic younger sister who tied him up and committed horrific acts in front of him, including mutilation and murder.
Five years later, he finally escapes, only for both of them to be hit by a truck and killed. He then wakes up in a void where a goddess tells him that he's going to be reincarnated in another world, and that his sister will be reincarnated in the same world.



Then he wakes up as Jack Lieber, the baby son of a count. His new parents dote over him and observe that he's been born with innate magic power. Jack vows to use this power to protect everyone from his sister.



